# session value not updating in theme variable for anonymous user

Tags: 8, theming, forms

I am working on multi-level forms, and storing form values in session to display result on final page with some form values. but its works fine only for authenticates users.

For anonymous users session value updates only after clearing cache on the page. but values updates in session variables but doesn't update in theme variables.

Tried all methods:

- `\Drupal::request()->getSession();`
- `\Drupal::service('user.private_tempstore')->get('module');`
- `$_SESSION['module']`

Same results for all. Please help!!

Comment: If you want to have dynamic values per-anonymous user you have to implement lazy builder, otherwise you will have these exact caching issues(that's how caching works).

Comment: Is there any other method I can store forms value (user inputs) in a multi-step form  and then render/display all the values captured via controller ?

Comment: check out ajax forms [#188730]